Limitations of propensity score matching
While studying propensity score matching, I was struck by the following thought:
When we are running a logistic regression model to estimate $p(Z=1∣X)$ through some form of parametrization and we are not conducting exact matching, how can we be sure that we in the end are matching similar covariates? In general, we would expect that. However, by chance, very different covariates might have similar propensity scores, possibly because they were both unlikely to receive the treatment. In such cases, when we match them, we are effectively matching very different covariates. Can someone clarify if this is a general issue, and if so, what do we usually do about it—such as post-matching covariate checks?

Propensity score matching (PSM) does not aim to guarantee that we have matching similar covariates but rather aims to replicate a quasi-randomised design. We aim to replicate a situation where the assignment mechanism is not dependent on the potential outcome (i.e. it is unconfounded). Matching on the propensity score allows us to assume that we respect the conditional independence assumption (which itself is really just a way of saying unconfoundedness); suggesting that conditional on a set of covariates $X_j$ the treatment indicator $W_i$ for the $i$-th subject is independent of $Y_i(0), Y_i(1)$ the respective potential outcomes for subject $i$. (or in symbolically: $W_i$ $\perp$ $Y_i(0), Y_i(1) $|$X_{ij}$) (See Chap. 21 Assessing Unconfoundedness in Causal Inference for Statistics, Social, and Biomedical Sciences An Introduction (2015) by Imbens and Rubin for an authorative source on the matter)
The above being said, yes, you are right, simple checks on covariates balance can fail in the case you mention. For example, a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test might suggest that certain covariates coming from the treated and control group have different distributions. While suboptimal, that doesn't necessitate that PSM failed, we still can do visual checks to assess if PSM worked. First, by plotting the distribution of propensity scores for treated and control groups before and after matching. After matching, the distributions should be similar. And then by doing a QQ-plot to compare the distribution of propensity scores between the two groups. Obviously, we need to have "some" similarity to our underlying covariate distributions (e.g. ensure we have (at least) common support between the covariates) as severe imbalances might still be problematic for the credibility of the unconfoundedness assumption. As whole, though, "matching very different covariates" between two subjects $i$ and $k$ is not indicative of a PSM failure.
As a final note: PSM is not great. (e.g. see: Why Propensity Scores Should Not Be Used for Matching (2019) by King & Nielsen) Propensity scores can be much more useful for techniques like doubly-robust estimators, (e.g. see: Doubly robust estimation of causal effects (2011) by Fank et al.) where we combine propensity score modelling with outcome regression to protect against misspecification of either the outcome model or the propensity score model. Similarly, if covariate balance is what we are really after, using something like Entropy Balancing (EB) is more appropriate. (e.g. see: Entropy Balancing for Causal Effects (2012) by Hainmueller)

Probably one of the largest limitations with propensity score matching is that it is only really firmly established in a frequentist framework. In fact, it was only until recently that researchers started using full Bayesian updating to fit models that used propensity score matching (see Liao et al, 2020).
A really great discussion on propensity score matching in a Bayesian context can be found here and here. Andrew Heiss shows how to do this using the brms package. However, you'll notice that as always, things with Bayesian methods also take longer, so it is not as computationally friendly as frequentist propensity score matching either.
References
Liao, Shirley X., and Corwin M. Zigler. 2020. “Uncertainty in the Design Stage of Two-Stage Bayesian Propensity Score Analysis.” Statistics in Medicine 39 (17): 2265–90. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.8486.
